# The use of a reference variable in this java code

Tags: java, class, reference, composition

Why is the reference variable ‚Input inside‘ necessary?
How does the ‚Input inside‘ work here?

What does the code: The code adds 5 to the x-value (in this case 4) and uses the square of the new value. So (4+5)^2.

Thank you.

Code:

```
abstract class Input {

    protected Input inside;

    public Input() {
    }

    public Input(Input inside) {
        this.inside = inside;
    }


    public int calculate(int value) {
        if(inside == null) {
            return value;
        }
        return inside.calculate(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Input chaincalculate = new Square(new AddFive());
        int x;
        x = 4;
        System.out.println("The value is: " + (int) chaincalculate.calculate(x));
    }
}
     
class AddFive extends Input {

    public AddFive() {
    }

    public AddFive(Input inside) {
        super(inside);
    }

    public int calculate(int value) {
        value = super.calculate(value);
        return value+5;
    }
}

class Square extends Input {

    public Square() {
    }

    public Square(Input inside) {
        super(inside);
    }

    public int calculate(int value) {
        value = super.calculate(value);
        return value * value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might be a rather contrived example to show how you can compose classes together. Sure, you _could_ just do `x = (4 + 5) * (4 + 5)`, but the point is not "you can do calculations in this weird way". Wherever you read this from, it should tell you what the point of this is.

Comment: You can debug the code and check the flow there if you are bent specifically towards how the flow is. Check it out in Intellij. Its very straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to debug it with Intellij. But I couldn't see the flow. I think I did something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

All the classes **extending the abstract class Input**, have their own **calculate methods**, and since, these classes, would want to use the **abstract class Calculate method**, the reference variable *input inside* is necessary to invoke/reference the **calculate method** residing in **Input abstract class**, to support the **method chaining** implemented in the code

Comment: Thank you. It make sense. But why do I need 2 Constructor?:                                          
         public Input() {
    }

    'public Input(Input inside) {
        this.inside = inside;
    }'